# filling an array with a date from user input

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, tokenize

So I am trying to fill an array with the date in a specific format (0000/00/00) then tokenize it on the "/" characters, then print it back in the format MM-DD-YYYY. I am having some trouble with tokenizing it. I'm new to this, what did I miss?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String[] date = new String[1];
    date[0] = "0000/00/00";
    
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter your date, format must be YYYY/MM/DD - include slashes");
    
        date[0] = s.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < date.length; i++)
            String[] tokens = date[i].split("/");

    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: I recommend to use a library for this. I like https://picocli.info/ .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

String str[] = date[i].split("\\\");